# I have problems with UV mapping and texturing

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Im trying to texture my Character using texture paint, the UV unwraps pretty good, but the node editor sets the material to black, when i klick "use nodes" and then when i enter texture paint it says missing data, anyway i do it the brush wont put color on my Model im not sure what im suppose to do?

[image]

Comment: have u tried to change the color of the material from black to some other color

Comment: Yeah i've cahnged the colors on the slider in Tools to the left, aswell as in material pannel to the right, but nothing does the trick, it just wont put color on the character :/

Comment: Click on the material panel and to right hand nodes panel under properties click new and change the color

Comment: Uncheck *Use Nodes*, it's better to paint texture wihtout material nodes in BI. Once they aren't active you should be able to choose the created image to use it as  a material slot.

Comment: Mr. Zak is right - you will need to not work with nodes to paint in Blender Render materials. Once you have saved your image slots to disk and saved all your painting, you can turn on 'use nodes' and reference them with a Texture node as long as they are added to your material in the texture panel in the Properties editor.